# R melt subcategories

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

I'm trying to melt a table (csv) with subcategories but for some reason cannot get the desired result with melt.array

I have:

```
Region,Sender,Afghanistan,,,,
,,Adult,,Minor,,
,,Male ,Female,Male,Female,
EEA,Austria,165,8,6,10,
....
```

need:

```
Reg Send    Rec         Age   Gender  Value
EEA Austria Afghanistan Adult Male    165
EEA Austria Afghanistan Adult Female  8
EEA Austria Afghanistan Adult Male    6
EEA Austria Afghanistan Adult Female  10
....
```

and would be most grateful for some help!

Comment: Is the first table your csv file? Can you paste it in with commas as well?

Comment: sorry its not very readable in the comments section

Comment: you are right! I changed the original code.

Comment: sorry abt it but now the output is confusing

Comment: I got a bit carried away there. Now we have it though. Any ideas? I am trying to map a large set of deportation data and am not the best at data wrangling!

Comment: Btw, if the table comes from an excel pivot table, you can use R to read in the raw data. Or you can double click on Grand Total and save down the data as csv

Answer (score 0):

dont have a very elegant way because of the structure but zoo::na.locf might be what you are looking for

```
library(zoo)
data <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
                                                                    "EEA", "Region"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                          1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "Austria", "Sender"), class = "factor"), 
                       V3 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("165", "Adult", 
                                                                    "Afghanistan", "Male "), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("", "8", "Female"), class = "factor"), 
                       V5 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("", "6", "Male", 
                                                                    "Minor"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                  2L), .Label = c("", "10", "Female"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 

data[1:3,][data[1:3,]==""] <- NA
data <- na.locf(zoo(data), fromLast=F)
df <- cbind(as.character(data$V1[4]), as.character(temp$V2[4]),
          data.frame(na.locf(zoo(t(data)), fromLast=F)[-(1:2),]))
setNames(df, c("Reg","Send","Rec","Age","Gender", "Value"))
```